# Flag a comment as misleading

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

Recently a comment was made by a user on my question. I really appreciate the comenter trying to help. But the commenter misunderstood my question and I even received an answer based on this comment.

I want to prevent comments that make others misunderstand the question or mislead others.

What should we do if a comment by a user is misleading other users?

Comment: I know next to nothing about Windows .NET GUI stuff, but your question seemed a bit confusing to follow. On first read, I thought your issue was related to how swipes on content move the content in the direction of the swipe, and thus the scrollbar in the opposite direction of the swipe (expected behavior and what comments and answers seem to refer to), but I think you are actually trying describe some other issue?

Comment: Have you considered *responding to the comment*?

Comment: Well, he did respond, @pekka, but the follow-up responses have all been deleted. All that remains is Hans's original comment. And now this Meta question.

Comment: @Kira Obsolete of course references one of the reasons comments are considered temporary.  Sometimes a question needs clarification, such as what yours may have required.  If Hans' comment was directed at an earlier version of the question, and the question changed so significantly that it no longer applies, then the obsolete flag would be relevant.

Comment: You asked him to run the code to verify the bug himself. He replied that the code you've shown does not actually use or alter any properties of the VScrollBar class. I cannot disagree with that. And it doesn't change the fact that what you claim is a bug rather appears to be the standard behavior of scroll bar controls in Windows. I was going to try and see if I could reproduce this behavior with a standard scroll bar on a window, but your attitude toward those trying to help has caused me to reconsider. You never addressed Hans's question of why you need a VScrollBar in the first place.

Comment: Coincidentally, the evidence is now gone. I remember it rather clearly, though. You are, of course, not obligated to answer everyone's questions. Nor are we obligated to answer yours.

Comment: The purpose of a question isn't to hold snippets of what other people say in answers/comments along with your replies.  You've already responded to them in your own comments below.  Please don't deface your question with unrelated responses.

Comment: @gnat, there is no solution to that question

Answer (score 25):

> Recently Hans Passant made a comment on my question.

This tends to happen when you post a question and add a bounty to it. You asked for attention, and you got it. And considering Hans is an expert on Windows programming, it's hard to imagine how this could ever be a bad thing.

> The comment is misleading others. I even received an answer based on this comment which is not relevant.

That is not the fault of the commenter, but rather the fault of the others who are being "misled". There is absolutely no evidence that he commented with the express intent of being misleading.

If you want to argue that his comment is incorrect, either add a reply of your own or (preferably) update the question to incorporate your response.

Honestly, this should have been your first move upon receiving a comment from someone. Even if they're wrong, others are likely to be confused about the same sort of things. *Especially* if your question has a bounty attached to it and is going to be attracting extra attention. Presumably, you want to increase your odds of getting a helpful answer. Burying your head in the sand  and asking him to remove the comment does little to increase these odds.

> it drew me a few down vote.

Well, one of those downvotes was mine. I also upvoted Hans's comment, because it was an excellent summary of the reasons why I was (a) confused about your question, and (b) electing to downvote it.

I had arrived at precisely the same conclusions as Hans while reading the question, *before* ever getting to the comments at the bottom. I had been mentally composing a similar comment of my own. His remarks did not influence my evaluation of the question; I only found that I agreed with him after independently drawing the same conclusion.

Whether this means we are both complete ignoramuses when it comes to Windows UI programming, or whether it means that your question is unclear and contains erroneous assumptions, is something that you'll have to decide.

> He made two comments. After flagging, they removed one but still the misleading one is there.

I see that he removed at least one of his comments. It was there when I looked at the question before going to bed last night, but it is gone now. The comment remains is the one that is both helpful and correct. Again, directing your ire at the comment and/or the commenter is unproductive.

It is also somewhat rude. You do not have the right to "control" who leaves comments on your questions.

> What should we do if a comment by top user is misleading other users?

Address their concerns by editing the question. Or simply ignore their comment. Your choice.

The "top"-ness of the user is irrelevant. And if it wasn't already clear from my remarks above, I very much resent your implication that the people who downvoted your question were simply doing so because of Hans's reputation score.

You are making the classic mistake that so many askers do: you start out assuming that you know everything about the problem domain and that all of your assumptions are correct. This is setting yourself up for failure. If you are in a position where you have to ask for help, you are probably *not* right about everything. Not that there's anything wrong with that—none of us knows everything. But getting stuck and having to ask for help should imply a little bit of humility and willingness to re-evaluate your assumptions.

Comment: +1 for all our disagreements I think its safe to say that if hans can't understand what you meant with your question about a windows system then its probably because the question wasn't very good.

Comment: I know Hans made a comment about what he thought is correct. But look at the answer, his comment is influencing others rather than my question. This is the reason I'm asking to modify or delete the comment

Comment: @Kira The above justification does not justify what was said before.

Comment: Yes, I took your question here very personally. It accused people of having downvoted your question because they blindly read Hans's comment and agreed with him because of his reputation, downvoting your question because they were *misled*. You claimed again in a comment on the question that I was "misled" by his comment. I was not. I agreed with it. Big difference. I am also quite bothered by the fact that you thought it was necessary to start a Meta post calling Hans out for leaving a well-meaning comment on your question.

Comment: If your interpretation of my answer is *"cody gray came to the same conclusion as Hans. But after reading his comment, he upvoted the comment and downvoted the question"*, then perhaps you have a reading comprehension problem. I am rather tired of being insulted by you. It should be pretty clear from reading my answer that I had already decided to downvote the question by the time I got to the end. I was saved the hassle of typing my own comment because Hans had already done so. You appear to be throwing a fit because you disagree with him. Well, you got your wish; he deleted his comment.

Comment: @CodyGray, I am sorry, I never intend to hurt anyone. Please accept my apologies

Answer (score 21):

> Cody's answer misrepresent my personality...

Hell has no fury like an incompetent programmer that doesn't get what he wants.  Contributors invariably are the focus, nobody else within reach.  I'm used to it.  But there seems to be no reasonable upper bound to what degree you'll lash out.  This has to **stop** before it goes any further.

Cody is an *excellent* judge of character, he saw through your spiel even without the benefit of knowing about the crap you've been pulling all week.  Constantly posting nasty comments and deleting them again, filling my inbox with crap.  This is *stalking* behavior, by far the most creepiest aspect about the Internet.

You owe Cody a *big* apology for your dreadful characterization.

Behave yourself.

Comment: The user doesn't seem to realize how creepy Internet stalkers are.  I can only attempt to reverse the roles to give her some insight in how unacceptable this is.  How else do you stop somebody like that?

Comment: Fwiw, the moderator must have seen all of those comments but he didn't do anything about it.  Hard to do anything about it when somebody deletes and reposts comments constantly I assume.

Comment: @HansPassant, I am sorry if I hurt you in any way. I already apologized to Cody.

Comment: @HansPassant, I never thought my comments are bothering you this much. If I have known that I would never make any comments

Comment: @hans I certainly don't want to down play what is happening and I praise myself not having encountered what you (and moderators here) have to endure. Just hang in there,  we need you.

Comment: @HansPassant Just wait until a moderator responds to the second meta thread. I believe someone will rectify this

Comment: This has to **stop**.  I can't seem to get that message across.