# Is it appropriate to ask a user to remove their comment in order to not distract other users?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I have [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330889/jersey-where-to-define-the-users-who-follow-a-role) about **how to do something** using **this library** and there is a user that suggests using a **different library**. I am happy with my library and I would like to keep using it.

My question does not have a lot of views so I would like the new users who see the question to not read comments about **another library**

I asked that user to remove their comments, is that an appropriate action?

(By now they already removed some comments, but I am asking in general.)

Comment: Why do you not want users to see the link to the library?

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest that you edit the question instead, and clarify it without going too much in the details of why. Something like:

> Using another library is not within the scope of the question.

Comment: Regarding your suggested addendum: I'm not so sure that is what *Stack Overflow* is for. I'm too young a member to remember the "Too localized" reason, but there are modern alternatives, and surely they would be applicable to questions specifically stating "I can't use X". That is, there should *always* be room for alternatives - maybe not for the OP, but for everyone else.

Answer (score 3):

Not really.

Users can freely suggest things like that because if you're open to the idea then it could form an extremely useful answer that they've already started on. Simply commenting something like "thanks, but I'm not using/cannot use that library" should suffice and let others know that it isn't an option.

Don't forget that one of the core uses of comments is to try and find out a bit more about your question/situation and that can also help others that may be looking at the question - if the user deletes that comment then someone else will probably just ask the same thing in another comment.

Comment: @inetphantom either would be acceptable, the point here is more about **not** asking someone to _delete_ a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Comments like these are actually useful.

They might not be useful to *you*, but that does not mean they are useless to everyone else that comes across the question. Other people might be having a similar issue with the library you're using, but have no particular reason to continue using that library if there is another one that elegantly avoids the problem. Stack Overflow is not just a help desk. The purpose of its Q&A is much broader than the person who originally asks the question. It's okay if a comment isn't helpful to the original asker, as long as it might conceivably help someone else with a similar question.

Mind you, they are not *answers* to the question, assuming that the question specifically calls out your desire to continue using the same library. But they are still valid comments, and they contain useful information, so they should not be deleted.

Therefore, I do not think it is appropriate to ask that the comment be deleted on this basis alone. I also disagree with the claim that the comment is "distracting" to other users. You are not the first person to make this argument, but it still seems specious to me. [It arises from a failure to differentiate between a comment "distracting" a user, and a user *agreeing* with a comment on its own merit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333217/flag-a-comment-as-misleading/333228#333228). In this case, I might come across the question, have had the same problem with the library you're using, and agree that it is a simpler/better/preferable option to ditch the library and replace it with a different one. I understand that is not something you're willing to do at this time, and is therefore not an answer to the question. But it doesn't mean that I was distracted by the comment and, thus afflicted, unable to think independently about or answer your question. Chances are good that I would have posted the same comment if it hadn't already been posted, and even if I didn't take time to post a comment, I wouldn't have had an answer for your question, because I solved the problem myself by switching libraries.

So please do not assume that comments "distract" people and seek their removal on that basis. You do not have final arbitration power over the comments left on your question. Comments should only be removed if they are offensive, obviously irrelevant, or have been rendered obsolete by circumstances (*e.g.*, edits to the post). Aside from that, users can and do think for themselves, independent of any comments. It strikes me as extremely patronizing to assume otherwise. If the person is so unable to think for themselves that they are hopelessly distracted by a comment, you probably don't want them answering your question anyway.

As others have said, you can and should stave off misunderstandings by editing your question (now and in the future) to explicitly call out any and all requirements that you may have, including stipulations that upgrading to a newer version of a library/tool/language/etc. is not an option, that switching to an alternative is not an option, etc. If people post *answers* that ignore these stipulations from the question, they are not an answers and you should feel free to downvote them.